# duplicate lang item in crate std (which ansi_term depends on): panic_impl - Cannot use dependency

Tags: polkadot, parachain, frontier

I was trying to use this `ansi_term` dependency in my project/precompiles/utils/src/lib.rs.

Here is my file structure:

```
my_parachain/
├── ...
└──precompiles/utils
     ├── macro
     ├── src/lib.rs
     └── Cargo.toml
```

after adding the following in the Cargo.toml above

```
ansi_term = "0.12.1"
```

All can compile. ansi_term was also found to be 0.12.1 in my Cargo.lock already before adding that in the Cargo.toml.

but when I want to use this `ansi_term` dependency by adding the following line in my project/precompiles/utils/src/lib.rs

```
use ansi_term::Colour;
```

then I got this error:

```
 error: duplicate lang item in crate `std` (which `ansi_term` depends on): `panic_impl`.
    |
    = note: the lang item is first defined in crate `sp_io` (which `frame_support` depends on)
    = note: first definition in `sp_io` loaded from .../target/release/wbuild/hero-runtime/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/deps/libsp_io-825169ab8c4ddb77.rmeta
    = note: second definition in `std` loaded from /home/user2038/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/wasm32-unknown-unknown/lib/libstd-a237209e92b55a70.rlib

  error: duplicate lang item in crate `std` (which `ansi_term` depends on): `oom`.
    |
    = note: the lang item is first defined in crate `sp_io` (which `frame_support` depends on)
    = note: first definition in `sp_io` loaded from .../target/release/wbuild/hero-runtime/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/deps/libsp_io-825169ab8c4ddb77.rmeta
    = note: second definition in `std` loaded from /home/user2038/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/wasm32-unknown-unknown/lib/libstd-a237209e92b55a70.rlib

  warning: `precompile-utils` (lib) generated 1 warning
  error: could not compile `precompile-utils` due to 2 previous errors; 1 warning emitted
```

But if I remove `use ansi_term::Colour;` in precompiles/utils/src/lib.rs, then all can compile again.

What went wrong???

Comment: Where do you want to use this crate? In a pallet or just in a test?

Comment: @OliverTale-Yazdi in my project/precompiles/utils/src/lib.rs, which is for running precompile codes, not a pallet nor a test